# MS Access Invalid use of Null (Error 94)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Can someone please explain why when I remove my last line of code it works but if I add my last line of code I get the ERROR 94

```
'Variable to set the Event ID too
Dim eventID As Integer
'Variable to set the Event Name too
Dim eventName As String
'Variable to hold the string condition for the Event ID
Dim eventStrCriteria As String
'Variable to hold the Members ID
Dim memberID As Long

memberID = CLng(Me.Text18)
eventStrCriteria = "isNull([check-OutDate]) And (employeeID = " & memberID & ")"
eventID = DLookup("[personelID]", "[tbl_ics238Table]", eventStrCriteria)
MsgBox DLookup("[eventName]", "[tbl_EventInformation]", "[eventID] =" & eventID)
```

Comment: MsgBox expects a string. Apparently the DLookup() is returning Null. Why would it not find an event name?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an answer, more comment but can't yet, but

```
eventID = DLookup("[personelID]", "[tbl_ics238Table]", strCriteria)
```

should probably be

```
eventID = DLookup("[personelID]", "[tbl_ics238Table]", **eventstrCriteria**)
```

(remove asterix)

That would account for the first dlookup() returning a null (I think), which would then make the second dlookup error out.

Comment: Thank you for the catch. I did change the code and got the same answer. I know that the event ID does work I put in a message box and it gave me the correct answer. I know just have to figure out why the last line causes the error. (I also fixed the code up top

Comment: Any chance the eventid is stored as a string in the tbl_eventinformation? Other thing to confirm is that the last dlookup is returning a null. If you assign it to a variant typed variable, can you do null tests and confirm that the second dlookup is the root source of the error?